# Can I use ggsave to save a plot I've created using base R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble saving high-resolution graphs in R and want to try to use the ggsave function. However, my code that loops through and creates 12 plots at once is written in base R and I don't want to re-write it using ggplot2. So far it hasn't worked, any idea on if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

```
filename <- paste0(titles[i-2], ".png")
  dev.copy(png, filename, res = 300)
  dev.off()
```

Comment: Other differences aside, `ggsave` is literally just a wrapper around the base R plot device functions. Even if you could get it to work with base R plots, it would not solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the resolution of the .png files of the graphs I save then?

Comment: The `png` function has a `res` argument so you can set the resolution to anything you want. See the `?png` help page for details. If you need more help than that, please at least post the code you are using that doesn't work well, preferably with a bit of sample input to make it reproducible.

Comment: Have tried that, that's why I thought of ggplot2.  See original post for code

Comment: The resolution of the plot in a saved `.png` file can be high or low for both base graphics and ggplot2, they are both capable. You said you tried using `png(..., res)` and it didn't work for you? I use that most days and haven't had a problem, perhaps there is something else wrong. Please post a reproducible problem including sample data (if needed, don't need much to demonstrate image resolution/quality) and the code you use to plot the code and save to a file (augmenting what you have above).

Comment: While not necessary as explained in the other comments, you can `wrap_elements` of most any content (including base plots) into a `ggsave`able object with {patchwork}: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html#adding-non-ggplot-content

Comment: I'd suggest specifying the height and width in inches or centimeters, not just the resolution. The default for `png` (again, if you see the `?png` help page) is 480 pixels by 480 pixels. By leaving the default height and width in pixels but specifying the 300 dpi, you are creating a very small image file (dimensionally).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
for (ii in 1:8){
thetas = seq(0,1,length=1000)*2*pi*ii
plot(sin(thetas),sin(7*thetas/8),typ="l",lwd=3)
filename <- paste0("harmonica",  ii, ".png")
dev.copy(png, filename, width = 1000)
dev.off()
print(ii)}
```

This returns 8 image files (pngs), with a resolution of 1000x 480.  You can change the height by specifying the height as an option in the dev.copy function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ggplotify** package:

```r
library(ggplotify)

p <- as.ggplot(~plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col="blue", pch=15))

ggsave("plot.png", plot = p)
```

This allows to easily make a grid of base plots with the **cowplot** package; see [thr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html).